# Can I check for snapshot vs release build in pom.xml?

Tags: maven

Is there a way to skip plugin execution or activate profile only for snapshot build (and for release build accordingly)?

Comment: Why do you like to do that? What's the purpose to make a differences between SNAPSHOT and release build ?

Comment: Custom config for maven-deploy-plugin (one project many artifacts) which requires repository url.

Comment: You are aware of [`distributionManagement`](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) in the pom.xml file ? Or what would you like to achieve?

Comment: I have that set up but configuration of maven-deploy-plugin for goal deploy-file requires url anyway and it overwrites dist management settings.

Comment: deploy-file sounds really like a case to use a repository manager instead.

Comment: In my case I'm using wagon to upload binaries that don't conform to Maven layout, but I only want to upload when doing a release build (since the upload site rejects versions with SNAPSHOT (and I don't want to clutter anyway))

Answer (score 1):

You have the distributionManagement tag in your pom.xml file like the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>release</id>
      <name>Corporate Repository</name>
      <url>http://server.name.com/releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <name>Propellors Snapshots</name>
      <url>http://server.name.com/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    ...
  </distributionManagement>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you can do it directly and flexibly.

Define a property which is activated only when Maven release plugin runs.  Then have your other plugins check the value of that property to decide whether to run or not.

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <preparationGoals>clean install -D release-flag=true</preparationGoals>
        <goals>deploy -D release-flag=true</goals>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

PS: A similar effect can be achieved using `-P release-profile` instead of `-D release-flag`

Comment: I am facing a similar situation and was wandering if using the maven-release-plugin can be detected out of the box without using the `-D` or `-P` options described above? Detected in a way that some build steps can be executed or properties be set only when doing a release using this plugin.